# Creating a facebook app with Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

Is it possible to create a facebook app using the Vaadin web toolkit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. At least there is one http://apps.facebook.com/possessed/ (not maybe the most beautiful one, but working). See also discussion at the vaadin forum: http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/169189

Answer (score 2):

Definetely possible. As you have an iframe for your app in facebook and you yourself host the application so there is no limit for that. You may also want to use [restfb](http://restfb.com/) for easily interacting fb graph api

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Facebook application using any language/framework/etc. The application is loaded in a Facebook Canvas (iframe), but your application isn't hosted on Facebook itself, rather it's hosted on an external app/web server of your choosing. So, as long as your server supports the language of your choosing, you are good to go.